# Benefit of using jQuery to modify CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently going over the ['Modifying HTML Elements'](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery) jQuery course on Codecademy and it is walking you through modifying CSS using jQuery. I was just wondering if there is a benefit of modifying the CSS via this method rather than just editing the actual CSS file?

Comment: well.... yes and no... it is often better to instead add/remove classes so that you can leave design to css. but simple show/hide functionality on the other hand, or moving something around, could make more sense in code since it has little to do with design. that and modifying it with js means that it will be modified on every page load, where as if you just fixed it in the CSS sheet it would be fixed immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a huge benefit, you can modify the CSS on your code dynamically within the page, for example, in response to some actions by the user. E.g. the user presses a button and you change the `color` of the button to `red`.

You should use CSS files to set the basic styles for the page, and then use jQuery in you code to add dynamism to the page and change styles in response to some events, like user interactions or web requests.

**Tip** One of the best approaches is to only use CSS classes defined in you CSS files. If you need to change the `color` of the button to `red`, make a class in your CSS file

```
button.pressed {
    color: red;
}
```

And use jQuery to add/remove that class, instead of directly modifiyng the CSS. This way you can have all your styles in your CSS file and in the code just use classes, this keeps the code cleaner.

This is probably kinda advanced, but keep it in mind!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the advice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying CSS via jQuery allows you to change the style of elements based on user interactions or other events/states. For example, changing the styling of invalid form inputs.

One of the best use cases of modifying CSS via jQuery is animating the position of an element. This is thanks in part's to jQuery's ability to change the CSS properties based on the element's current properties. See the example below.

***That said***, in many cases it's better to apply a class to an element and use CSS to style that specific class. The class can be toggled on/off as needed, preventing the need to reset CSS styles in jQuery.

```js
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
 
$( "#left" ).click(function(){
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 50px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```